# WooCommerce current category hide

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have done all the child category shows in each parent category. Now I want the current or active category not to be displayed when I am on the category page.

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$child_terms    = get_term_children ( $queried_object->term_id, 'product_cat' );
$main_term     = (is_wp_error($child_terms) || empty($child_terms)) ? get_term ( $queried_object->parent, 'product_cat' ) : $queried_object;

$terms_arg = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
    'orderby'       => 'name', 
    'hide_empty'    => false,
    'parent'        => $main_term->term_id,
) );

if( !empty( $terms_arg ) && !is_wp_error( $terms_arg ) ){

    foreach( $terms_arg as $display_term ){
        printf(
            '<div class="cat-list"><h3%s><a href="%s">%s</a></h3></div>',
            ($display_term->term_id == $queried_object->term_id) ? : '',
            esc_url(get_term_link($display_term->term_id)),
            $display_term->name,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem? what have you tried yourself, so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
foreach( $terms_arg as $display_term ){

    if( $display_term->term_id != $queried_object->term_id ) {
        printf(
            '<div class="cat-list"><h3><a href="%s">%s</a></h3></div>',
            esc_url(get_term_link($display_term->term_id)),
            $display_term->name,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well. But when the category thumbnail is displayed, it shows error. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

According to me get_terms() is having the options of exclude under the argument parameter

Try with below code

```
$terms_arg = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
'orderby'       => 'name', 
'hide_empty'    => false,
'parent'        => $main_term->term_id,
'exclude'       => $display_term->term_id, //assuming that $display_term->term_id is getting current category id
) );
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Error display .. Any  other idea...?